# How to access json constant dynamically from a state in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a constant json link this

```
export const errorMessages = {
   phoneno: '10 digits number used as your username.',
   password: 'Password is required',
   email: 'Email Address is required',
};
```

i can able to access above json link

> console.log(errorMessages.phoneno);

i need to access this json dynamically from state, something like this

```
this.setState({fieldName:"phoneno"});
console.log(errorMessages.this.state.fieldName);
```

Is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[]` denotes the key in object. For eg: errorMessages["phoneno"] will return the value of phoneno key in errorMessages  object. Try this

```
console.log(errorMessages[this.state.fieldName]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        errorMessages: {
            phoneno: '',
            password: '',
            email: '',
        }
    };
 }
```

//

after setting the initial state you will call api in componentWillMount() and get that JSON response in componentWillMount() you can do this

```
new_state = {}
new_state.errorMessages = {
    phoneno: '10 digits number used as your username.',
    password: 'Password is required',
    email: 'Email Address is required',
}

this.setState({...new_state})
```

you can use the state where ever you whant like eg: 
  this.state.errorMessages.phoneno

Comment: This does not answer OP question